# Elegant way to deal with null references in chained XElement axis methods

Tags: .net, linq-to-xml, xelement, method-chaining

Given something like this:

```
var results = theElement.Element("Blah").Element("Whatever").Elements("Something");
```

Is there an elegant way to deal with a null Blah or Whatever element so results is just null or empty in these cases?

I know I can split up the query and manually do these checks but was wondering if there was something more succinct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add some extension methods to do this for you. For the `Element` method you would return null or the element itself. For the `Elements` method you would return an empty result or the target elements.

These are the extension methods:

```
public static class XElementExtensions
{
    public static XElement ElementOrDefault(this XElement element, XName name)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        return element.Element(name);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> ElementsOrEmpty(this XElement element, XName name)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<XElement>();

        return element.Elements(name);
    }
}
```

You can use them in this manner:

```
var query = theElement.ElementOrDefault("Blah")
                      .ElementOrDefault("Whatever")
                      .ElementsOrEmpty("Something");
if (query.Any())
    // do something
else
    // no elements
```

If you're not querying for `ElementsOrEmpty` and your last request is for `ElementOrDefault` you would check for null instead of using the `Enumerable.Any` method.